# How to send several strings to database with jquery to a php-file by ajax-POST?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Given is:

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname'>
<input type='text' name='lastname' id='lastname'>
<input type='text' name='username' id='username'>
<input id='pw' name='pw' type='password'>
```

I try to submit the data with an ajax-post-request like this:

```
                var myData = "firstname="+ $('#firstname').val() + "&lastname="+ $('#lastname').val() + "&username="+ $('#username').val() + "&pw="+ $('#pw').val();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/register.php",
                dataType:"text",
                data:myData, //Form variables
                success:function(response){
                    $("#responds").append(response);
                }
```

How to submit this data in a kind of this way correctly tho the php-file which corresponds to the database? Is a `<form>` needed for submitting with a button?

Comment: A form is not _needed_ when you want to submit the data via AJAX (although it could make sense as a fallback, if JavaScript is not available.) But you should never assemble such a query string format yourself (your attempt for example lacks proper encoding, if one of the values would contains `&` this breaks already) - use https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ instead.

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem here? Do you actually have any PHP written to handle this request?

Comment: I don't think it is the right way to POST data to php file but if this is the case for you then i would like to see what you actually want to achieve on the server side.

Comment: Sure, just a simple insert in php/register.php. I don´t know how to submit the POST correctly to the PHP-file.

Comment: How you would achieve RopAli Munshi?

Comment: "I try to submit the data"  And what happens when you do? Are you getting errors?  If so, what are they?  Are you _checking_ for errors?  If you're _not_ getting errors, what _is_ happening that is different from what you expect?  "How do I submit data to PHP" is to broad a question to ask.  Please try to narrow this down to the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem as many have mentioned. Easiest from my point of view is to wrap the fields in a form.

1. Bind a [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event which fires a callback when your form is submitted.
2. [Serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form using `.serialize()` creating a text string in standard URL-encoded notation of all valid input fields and their values (so you don't have to build this query string yourself)
3. [Post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) your data using `$.post` and handle the response using the success callback

Below is a fully functional snippet. You can see the data sent to PostBin [here](http://postb.in/b/ADC3a3Vm).

```js
// PostBin CORS
$.ajaxSetup({crossDomain:true})

// Submit handler
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this)
  $.post(
    'http://postb.in/ADC3a3Vm',// replace with php/register.php
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(response){
      $("#response").append(response);
      $form[0].reset()
    }
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 
 <div id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `serialize()` jQuery function

```
var myData = $("form").serialize();
```

in this case `<form>` is required 
[Read here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)